# How to check all checkboxes when switch component in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to check a list of checkboxes when change a v-switch.
What I have is this:

This is switch component, if selectAll is true I want to check all checkboxes:

```
  <v-switch style="padding-right:15px;" v-model="selectAll" @change="handleChanging">
                        </v-switch>
```

Here is the list, each item has a checkbox before:

```
  <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in itemsEducators" :key="index">
      <v-list-item-action>
     <v-checkbox :key="item.title" :input-value="item.checked"> </v-checkbox>
             </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
               <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>{{ item.institution }} </v-list-item-subtitle>
                   </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
```

An here is js function:

```
     methods: {
        handleChanging() {
            if (this.selectAll === true) {
     //here I want to check all checkboxes
            } else {
     //here to uncheck all
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Like your `v-switch` every `v-checkbox` have a `v-model`. You just need to change the initial value in there.

Comment: sorry I didnt understood, can you explain me how?

Comment: `v-model` defines where your input (of any kind) get´s store but also, if you want to predefine something. So if you want your `v-checkbox` be checked, just change the `v-model` of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using this:

```
handleChanging() {    
   if (this.selectAll === true) {
      this.itemsEducators.forEach(x => x.checked = true);
   } else {
      this.itemsEducators.forEach(x => x.checked = false);
   }
}
```